# ¿Necesitamos [google]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Todo surge por el tag [google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) que de momento solo tiene 7 preguntas.

Todas tratan de temas distintos:

[image: captura-tag-google]
[image: captura-tag-google]

Que esten etiquetadas como google no aporta nada al tema, al contrario de tags como [google-maps](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) [google-play](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play) [google-app-engine](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine)

Deberia ser eliminada y puesta en la lista negra

---

**Actualización Agosto 2017**

Hoy encontré una pregunta etiquetada con google después seguí el tag y vi que había 34 preguntas

[image: Captura 34 preguntas con google]

Yo las borre de cada una de las preguntas personalmente, y re etiquete con las debidas

**Podemos ya ponerla en la lista negra**

El problema que veo es que la gente escribe

google [espacio] maps

Y se etiqueta con google y con maps, cuando lo adecuado seria usar [google-maps](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) y así pasa con otros productos de google

@Mariano me comento que solo los empleados pueden poner etiquetas en lista negra, me ayudan a logralo.

**Actualización 18/Agosto/2017**

Aparecieron dos preguntas mas

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google?sort=newest

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me quieren creer

Comment: Veo bien eliminarla ya que las otras que nombras si que son utilidades de la propia compañía y específicas de la misma por lo que está bien recalcarlo. En cuanto al nombre de las empresas, estoy contigo, no aportan nada a las etiquetas.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que te ayudemos a lograr que se ponga en la lista negra? Si te refieres a que quieres orientación, me parece que debería hacerse una nueva pregunta, pero esta vez con [meta-tag:soporte] y [meta-tag:solicitud-de-quemado]. En lo personal no estoy del todo convencido que las etiquetas con nombres de empresas deban quemarse.

Comment: @Rubén muchas gracias buen hombre

Comment: Yo si te creo, es más [¿Algún “malvado” que ponga a \[google\] en la lista negra?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2684/65)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se ha eliminado la etiqueta [google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) de 17 preguntas que la tenían el día de hoy. Esperemos que no reaparezca.

Relacionado:

- [¿Algún "malvado" que ponga a [google] en la lista negra?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2684/65)

Answer (score 9):

Considero se debería restringir únicamente a tener las etiquetas que estan definidas en SO en inglés, ya que fueron aprobadas y son utiles para una gran cantidad de usuarios.

Algunas tal vez tienen una cantidad pequeña de preguntas, pero en un futuro siendo que nuestra comunidad crece, creo que serían necesarias.

**En el caso de la etiqueta "Google" considero no debería existir, debería ser eliminada ya que es una etiqueta muy genérica**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

En el caso particular de [google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) estoy de acuerdo que se incluya en la **lista negra** pues veo muy poco probable que se use apropiadamente en buenas preguntas sobre www.google.com, o cualquiera de sus variantes que estén dentro de la temática del sitio por otro lado veo como muy probable que se incurra en incluirla "accidentalmente" ya que como se menciona en la pregunta es muy fácil que se escriba en las etiquetas "google" espacio "algo".