# ¿Algún "malvado" que ponga a [google] en la lista negra?

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-lista-negra

Como se explica en [¿Necesitamos [google]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1030/65), ocurre con cierta regularidad que al poner etiquetas se escriba "google" espacio "lo que sea" (maps, api, script, etc).

Ya se ha <s>"quemado" (eliminar)</s> eliminado [google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) repetidamente de las preguntas que la tenían pero sigue reapareciendo, así que se hace la atenta solicitud a nuestros recién electos moderadores a que tomen acción o nos dirijan en este tema.

---

Sobre el texto de alerta propongo los siguiente:

> La etiqueta "google" no está permitida
>
> Esta etiqueta ha sido prohibida pues resulta ser demasiado amplia y de poca utilidad. Si has querido indicar algo como "google maps", en lugar de espacios usa guiones (ejemplo: "google-maps").

---

Lo de "malvado" es en relación al lema "don't be evil" que se podría traducir como no seas malvado, el cual era usado por los fundadores de Google.

Comment: hola JuanM.. dice el infierno que la esta esperando de brazos abiertos...

Comment: @Mariano acabo de intentar añadir la etiqueta y lo he hecho sin problema, luego no está aún en la lista negra.

Comment: @Mariano: Esta publicación es previa a la publicación de [¿Cuál es el proceso de remover etiquetas (quemarlas)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/65) En algunas publicaciones de SO Meta y Meta ES se utilizó el término "quemado" para referirse a eliminar la etiqueta de todas las preguntas. En fin, a la luz del proceso a seguir para [meta-tag:solicitud-de-quemado] no creo que valga la pena gastar mucho tiempo en discutir la terminología en este hilo sino más bien seguir el proceso adecuado o bien pedir clarificación sobre dicho proceso.

Comment: Por ejemplo, habría que agregar la etiqueta correcta, agregar las respuestas a los cuatro criterios, etc. Una de las cosas que me gustaría que fuera aclarada es si aquí también se requieren 20 votos.

Comment: @Rubén ok... Pero al leer "*ya se ha quemado*", a mí me confundió y no entendí de qué se trataba, hasta que entendí que solamente había sido eliminada de todas las preguntas por revisores

Answer (score 7, accepted):

¡Listo! Ya no se puede usar [google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) en preguntas nuevas (con texto de ayuda)

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparece el siguiente texto:

> La etiqueta "google" no está permitida.
>
> Esta etiqueta ha sido prohibida pues resulta ser demasiado amplia y de poca utilidad. Si has querido indicar algo como "google maps", en lugar de espacios usa guiones (ejemplo: "google-maps").