# ¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar las etiquetas (quemarlas)?

Tags: soporte, solicitud-de-quemado, wiki-de-comunidad

## Criterios para la solicitud-de-quemado

(basados en [esta publicación](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) de Meta Stack Overflow)

[Existen cuatro criterios para considerar una solicitud-de-quemado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

(el artículo está en inglés)

> 1. ¿Describe el contenido de las preguntas en donde es aplicada la etiqueta? ¿Es clara?
> 2. ¿Se encuentra el concepto en conformidad con el tema de la comunidad?
> 3. ¿Añade la etiqueta algún contenido valioso a la aportación?
> 4. ¿Significa lo mismo en todos los contextos comunes?
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> Si te quedas pensando en que estos criterios van a ser muy tediosos para evaluar a una etiqueta asignada a múltiples preguntas, entonces *estás completamente en lo correcto* - es por eso que nos quedamos *escépticos* hacia muchas de estas solicitudes en la rara ocasión en que tomamos el tiempo necesario para aceptarlas. Si te quedas pensando en que no vale el esfuerzo en eliminar etiquetas que no parecen estar molestando a nadie, **eres más astuto que la mitad de la gente que está pidiendo estas quemaduras**. Si *parece ser* trabajo sin chiste, probablemente *lo es*...
>
> Pero a veces, no lo es. Hay veces en las etiquetas estorban, crean confusión, empiezan peleas, o toman el lugar de **mejores** etiquetas...

La etiqueta debe fallar **todas** estas pruebas para ser considerada para la quemadura. **Si es claro que eliminar la etiqueta va a causar mas daño que beneficio** entonces es obvio el dejarla en paz.

Hubiera sido mas fácil el dejar esto a la votación, pero... eso nos llevaría a más desacuerdos. [Tu disgusto hacia un juego frustrante nunca debe resultar en la destrucción de una etiqueta válida.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273079/we-have-a-flappy-bird-clone-tag-really). (enlace en inglés)

Justo y cuando estés convencido de que la etiqueta en cuestión cumple con *todos* los requisitos y es un buena candidata para el proceso de la quemadura, puedes continuar al siguiente paso. Recuerda que la solicitud-de-quemado se trata de [mantener los bordes limpios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) (enlace en inglés).

Así que:

1. Si tienes conocimiento **autoritativo** de las tecnologías relevantes a la etiqueta *y* has **conferido** con al menos un otro miembro confiable de la comunidad *y* se trata de una etiqueta que lleva un **número pequeño** de preguntas (< 50), puedes entonces eliminarla la tú mismo con o sin ayuda *ad hoc.*
2. **De lo contrario**, *debes* seguir el proceso comunitario para la solicitud-de-quemado descrito en lo siguiente.

---

## Proceso de la solicitud-de-quemado

1. **Propuesta:** La parte interesada formula una [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado) en una pregunta Meta apropiadamente nombrada, dando la justificación de los cuatro criterios mencionados anteriormente. Comentarios iniciales se coleccionarán, las justificaciones se mejorarán, y la propuesta recibirá votos.

   Una solicitud-de-quemado no es más que una *propuesta* hasta que no reciba por lo menos una puntuación de 20. Si nunca llega a esta puntuación, no se actuará en cumplir la solicitud. No se debe interpretar la apatía como si fuera señal de soporte.

2. **Destacado:** Para las solicitudes-de-quemado que cumplan o superen la puntuación de 20, el paso siguiente es el "destacado"—que es importante para acumular comentarios de la comunidad entera incluyendo a los que no visitan el sitio Meta normalmente. Esto les permite demostrar su apoyo a la [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado) *y también* da la oportunidad a otros que estén en desacuerdo a poder expresar sus puntos de vista.

   - Un moderador pondrá la etiqueta [destacado](/questions/tagged/destacado) a la solicitud-de-quemado por 36–48 horas (preferiblemente entre semana, no en un finde). Preguntas destacadas se podrán ver en el boletín comunitario en el sitio principal para poder proveer suficiente exposición a la membresía.
     <sub>([Atención: la selección para destacar las solicitudes-de-quemado es un proceso manual así que puede existir una cola o otros factores limitantes.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356821) (enlace en inglés). Haremos lo mejor para escoger las más criticas, más impactantes solicitudes dentro de un horario semi-regular.)</sub>
   - [Títulos con juego de palabras](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests) (enlace en inglés) no se admitirán y son prohibidas durante esta fase. El moderaror las reemplazará y les cambiará el título usando el siguiente formato, *"¿Deberíamos quemar la etiqueta [el nombre de la etiqueta]?*"
   - La siguiente [advertencia escondida](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317046) y aviso público se pondrán al principio de la publicación:

     ```
     <!-- Nota del moderador a los editores:
     No cambien el titulo de la pregunta mientras esta [destacado]. ¡No usen juegos de palabras!

     Si se ignora esta nota, se considerará como abuso y se tratará debidamente.
     -->

     *Esta etiqueta está en la segunda fase del proceso de quemadura descrito [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2839/). La pregunta y los comentarios han sido limpiados para permitir discusiones dentro del tema de esta etiqueta - no cambien eso.
     Si quieres discutir este proceso, publica una pregunta nueva en Meta.*

     -----
     ```
   - El moderador pondrá un aviso (*Destacado: solicitud-de-quemado*), lo cual mostrará una bandera grande debajo de la pregunta.
   - Al poner el aviso, el moderador limpiará los comentarios obsoletos, verbosos, o sin chiste para hacer espacio para las discusiones de importancia. Tipicamente el moderador dejará un comentario notando la puntuación de la publicación antes de destacarla.

   #### ¡No empiezen a quitar la etiqueta durante las fases de la "propuesta" y el "detacado"!

3. **Decisión:** Después de su tiempo en la luz brillante, un moderador revisará la solicitud y todos los argumentos a favor/a contra. Ellos decidirán en este paso si se continuará el proceso de la quemadura o si se terminará temprano. Un gran influjo de votos en contra o comentarios nuevos durante la fase del "destacado" es una señal de esperar antes de continuar con la quemada.

   Usando los votos, las respuestas, y los comentarios para juzgar el consenso de la comunidad, el moderador decidirá si:

   - Poner fin al proceso al agregar la etiqueta [estado-rechazado](/questions/tagged/estado-rechazado) a la pregunta. Esto señala que la comunidad ha decidido en contra de la quemadura de la etiqueta por ahora. Si se encuentra nueva evidencia que merece una revaluación de la decisión entonces una nueva propuesta se puede empezar.
   - Encontrar una etiqueta que se puede limpiar fácilmente de inmediato, sin limpieza extensiva, y mover al paso #5.
   - Seguir al siguiente paso del proceso.

4. **La limpieza y la quemada :** Durante esta fase:

   - Un moderador pondrá la etiqueta [estado-planificado](/questions/tagged/estado-planificado) en la pregunta señalando que la quemada esta en progreso.
   - El título se cambiará en la siguiente manera: *"La etiqueta [nombre de etiqueta] esta en preparación de ser quemada"*
   - El aviso se actualizará a *La solicitud-de-quemado esta progresando*.
   - El tag de wiki se editará a *"¡FAVOR DE NO USAR! Esta etiqueta esta siendo quemada. Véase: <link a la pregunta en Meta>"* (o la etiqueta será puesta en la lista negra).
   - Para que el proceso sea visible, una respuesta "wiki de comunidad" se publicará, si es que no existe todavía que provea lo siguiente:

     ```
     # Observaciones/Guía para re-etiquetar:

     <Las observaciones sobre el uso actual de la etiqueta y la orientación
     ```

     para limpiarla.  Esto debe ser resumido o trasladado directamente de otras discusiones previas.>

     ```
     # Progreso:

     La Etiqueta [tag:tag] esta en proceso de ser quemada. Puedes ayudar al revisar otras preguntas con esta etiqueta y...

     - **editar** preguntas (para mejorar la pregunta *y* eliminar la etiqueta),
     - **reportar/cerrar** preguntas que son duplicados/fuera de tema/no claras/demasiado amplias/basadas en opiniones,
     - filtrando en esta etiqueta en la [Cola de votos de cierre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close),
     - **votar** en preguntas con esta etiqueta,
     - votar para **eliminar** las preguntas con esta etiqueta (después de que se hayan cerrado, pero solamente si la Pregunta/Respuesta no contiene nada de valor)

     Algunos enlaces para ayudar en este proceso: 

     - [Abiertas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btag%5D+closed%3Ano)
     - [Cerradas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btag%5D+closed%3Ayes)
     - [Sin respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btag%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
     - [Sin respuesas aceptadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btag%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

     # Recuerden que la quemada es un esfuerzo de limpieza!

     ### Rescaten lo que se pueda en donde es posible al editar y re-etiquetar.

     No queremos destruir al azar así que el rescatar las publicaciones debe ser la primera prioridad. Si una pregunta puede ser salvada, por favor edítala. Esa edición deberá mejorar *todos* los problemas con la pregunta *y* eliminar la etiqueta [tag:tag], al reemplazarla con otra, como se describe anteriormente.

     ### Preguntas que no se pueden salvar deben ser reportadas/cerradas. No necesitan ser re-etiquetadas.

     Si la pregunta no es apropiada para este sitio, no te preocupes sobre si debes o no eliminar la etiqueta [tag:tag].j Simplemente repórtala/ciérrala  en la pregunta en donde se encuentra.

     Al final del proceso de la quemada, todas las preguntas que queden con esa etiqueta [tag:tag] deben estar cerradas. Se eliminarán en grupo, cosa que quitará la etiqueta del sistema automáticamente con distracciones mínimas.

     ### Pide ayuda si lo necesitas.
     ```

     Si tienes alguna pregunta sobre preguntas específicas o sobre el proceso en general, pr favor dejen un comentario en esta publicación.

   La persona que publique esta respuesta es la que será vista como el líder en el esfuerzo de la quemada de esa etiqueta. Esa persona puede ser:

   - la persona que originalmente publicó la solicitud-de-quemado,
   - otra persona dedicada e interesada en este proceso,
   - una sala de chat específica al tema,
   - el moderador que nos trajo a este punto del proceso.

5. **Finalización:** En cuanto el paso #4 se haya completado, el líder de la solicitud la reportará para que un moderador la pueda ver.

   El moderador contactará el gerente de comunidades para eliminar cualquier pregunta con puntos negativos con la etiqueta condenada a desaparecer y quitará la etiqueta del sistema por completo.

   En cuanto la etiqueta se haya removido, el moderador:

   - Pondrá la etiqueta [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) a la pregunta.
   - Cambiar el aviso público a *Solicitud-de-quemado completada*.
   - Editar el título de la pregunta a algo aburrido como *" La etiqueta [nombre de la etiqueta] se ha quemado"*

---

## Ejemplos de [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado) completadas (en inglés)

Aquí algunas propuestas de [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado). Estas etiquetas fueron quemadas al seguir los pasos indicados anteriormente. (enlaces en inglés).

[[entry]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349778/another-entry-on-the-burnination-list)     [[research]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323081/we-have-stopped-doing-research)     [[guidelines]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298984/we-dont-need-guidelines)     [[priority]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285084/burninate-priority)

Aquí algunos ejemplos de solicitudes [estado-rechazado](/questions/tagged/estado-rechazado) [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado): (enlaces en inglés)

[[nokia]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355199/should-we-burninate-nokia)     [[chemistry]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342959/should-we-burninate-chemistry)     [[cisco]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352209/burninate-the-cisco-tag)

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de cambiar algunos nombres de meta-etiquetas, por ejemplo, dado que tenemos [meta-tag:estado-completado], de igual forma deberíamos tener [meta-tag:estado-planificado] y [meta-tag:estado-rechazado].

Comment: @Flxtr ¡Te lo agradezco! Ahora se ve mejor. :)

Comment: En la advertencia escondida del paso 2, del proceso de quemado dice en la referencia original "*If you ignore this note, moderator will suspend your account for a week.*". ¿Aplicaría el mismo criterio para [es.so]? Considero que sería mejor explicar cuál sería el debido tratado que se daría ;)

Comment: Celebro que se traduzca la versión inglesa del proceso de quemado de etiquetas. Lo que me cojea bastante es que se traduzca literalmente, sin poner absolutamente nada propio de este sitio. Se menciona que se podría haber debatido cómo hacerlo y, de hecho, hace un tiempo pregunté sobre ello: [¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2093/83), sin respuesta. Se copia el requerimiento de 20 votos, algo inasumible en SOes.Si este sitio debe ser diferente de SO, ¿en qué se está marcando la diferencia?

Comment: La palabra **removal** no se traduce como como **remover**. Se traduce como **eliminar** o **eliminación**. Tal y como está escrito el título pregunta cómo agitar las etiquetas.

Comment: Me parece que solicitar 20 votos para que una solicitud de quemado es excesivo en SOes considerando que rara vez una pregunta logra ese nivel de votos. Sugiero se disminuya a 10.