# ¿Es posible eliminar la etiqueta [return] permanentemente?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado, solicitud-de-lista-negra

La etiqueta [return](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/return) es ambigua y no aporta ninguna información. Debería ser eliminada ahora que estamos a tiempo (sólo hay [9 preguntas relacionadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/return))

- Describe el contenido de las preguntas en donde es aplicada la etiqueta ¿Es clara? --> TODAS las preguntas menos una hablan de cómo retornar algo, de por qué su código no retorna lo esperado. Que es el fundamento de cómo funciona una función en cualquier lenguaje. Si es por esto, deberían tener una etiqueta `función` o algo similar... Sólo [una habla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125835/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-return-y-exit-en-bash) del comando return en bash y creo que `bash` es mejor indicio como etiqueta que return en este caso.
- ¿Se encuentra el concepto en conformidad con el tema de la comunidad? --> Está on-topic (no habla de gaticos ni de bicicletas checoslovacas) pero es ambiguo, como se acaba de ver en el punto anterior. No aclara nada sobre la pregunta.
- ¿Añade la etiqueta algún contenido valioso a la aportación? --> No lo creo. Apunta a algo básico (¿o a un comando?) que no aclara nada sobre el código de la pregunta.
- ¿Significa lo mismo en todos los contextos comunes? --> La ambiguedad en su uso hace difícil determinar si significa lo mismo siempre. No se sabe a qué concepto se refieren con return. ¿A la respuesta de un bloque de código? ¿Al comando bash?

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo. voto por quemarla definitivamente.

Comment: Una de las preguntas es mía :$

Comment: Falta información. Véase [¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar las etiquetas (quemarlas)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/65)

Comment: Ya añadí la información, @Rubén

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ¿Estás a favor o en contra de eliminar la etiqueta en cuestión de tu pregunta?

Comment: ¿Yo? A favor. Me di cuenta de que una era mía, porque las estaba mirando. Estaba tentado de editar las preguntas para quitar la etiqueta y dejar que muera sola.

Comment: De acuerdo en eliminarla (no sé quiénes pueden votar, pero si puedo tienen mi voto).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ya no hay preguntas con esta etiqueta, por lo que puede marcarse como resuelto.

Comment: @fedorqui marcada como completada. Muchas gracias a todos los que realizaron las ediciones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Procedamos con la eliminación de la etiqueta de las preguntas que la tienen. NOTA: Al editar se deben arreglar todos los problemas que tenga la pregunta.

## Explicación

Como sólo se trata de 9 preguntas y la más antigua es del 2017, pareciera que no es una etiqueta que sea "atractiva" y es muy probable que eliminándola de las preguntas que la tienen se resuelva el problema. Si reapeciera varias veces es entonces que habría que realizar el "proceso de quemado" (eliminar la etiqueta y agregar a la lista negra)

Comment: estoy de acuerdo. A lo que no me acostumbro es a esta manera de compartimentar la respuesta, ocupan más los títulos que el texto :P