# Eliminar etiqueta con errores de escritura

Tags: soporte, solicitud-de-quemado

Leyendo [esta publicacion en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2839/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-proceso-para-eliminar-las-etiquetas-quemarlas) sobre el proceso para quemar etiquetas, no veo que se mencionen errores de escritura.

A la etiqueta que me refiero es [hmtl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hmtl)

También noto que filtrando las [etiquetas creadas recientemente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new), aparecen varias que pensaría, solo se van a usar en una pregunta por un usuario, como por ejemplo la etiqueta [[semáforo]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sem%C3%A1foros)

¿Existe un sistema de limpieza de estas etiquetas? ¿Puedo crear a diestra y siniestra nuevas etiquetas alcanzada la reputación de 300? ¿Podemos moderar este comportamiento de otra forma a la indicada en el enlace inicial?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes solo editar la pregunta y cambiar la etiqueta para poner la etiqueta correcta

Comment: Muchas gracias @fedorqui, es la respuesta que buscaba