# enlistanegrar la etiqueta problema antes que sea un [problema]

Tags: discusión, estado-en-revisión, solicitud-de-lista-negra

<strike>Invoco al dese Trogdor el burninator para que se arme la quemación de la etiqueta [problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/problema), por ser demasiado inespecífica.</strike>

[image: trogdor]

Parece ser que anda durmiendo... así que... mejor que se arme **la lista negra** :3

Así la etiqueta dejará de ser un [problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/problema)

Comment: son 4 preguntas.. con eliminarla de cada una de ellas, alcanza...

Comment: de momento sí... pero la idea tras quemacionar la etiqueta es para que nadie más la use ni por error

Comment: suena logico... igual no es que aparece muy seguido... mas que quemarla, lo que vos estas pidiendo es que la mandemos a la lista negra.. quemarla es solo borrarla, y para eso alcanza con sacarla de las preguntas... se queman, cuando aparece demasiadas veces como para hacerla a mano...

Comment: No sabía de la lista negra, por favor entonces agrega eso en la respuesta para que otros lo aprendan también. Saludos.

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/324 mira aca

Comment: cool editado :3

Comment: Si la eliminás de las 4 preguntas, la etiqueta desaparece, y sólo un usuario con la suficiente reputación puede crearla... ¿Vale la pena el esfuerzo de poner en lista negra algo que no es tanto "problema"? .... Yo me preocuparía más por dejarle un mensaje al primer usuario con reputación que la creó

Comment: _enlistanegrar_, gran verbo :) De acuerdo con @Pollo, siempre al quite.

Comment: Aunque sean 4 preguntas, creo que sería bueno enviarla a la "lista negra" como comenta @RuslanLópez , A mi me parecen pocas incidencias ya que recuerdo haberla visto y quitarla en varias ocasiones.

Comment: ¿Estás diciendo que problema es un problema?

Comment: Ahora que existe, se está poniendo diariamente. @gbianchi ¿estáis en ello? Últimamente las preguntas sobre etiquetas en Meta están en el limbo, no sé si estáis procesándolas. Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' me venia encargando pero tuve unas semanas complicadas... ahora reviso...

Comment: Viendo cómo sigue esta publicación, aclaro que yo dije que se podía eliminar y ya, por un tema de sencillez, para no dedicar esfuerzos nomás... No tengo ningún argumento en contra de *enlistanegrar*. Y dudo que alguien tenga un "problema" con esto... Ya llevarlo a votación es dedicar más esfuerzos aún, jajaja, lo contrario a lo que intentaba decir

Comment: Apologies for the delay, @gbianchi — acknowledging this is on the CMs' backlog, and we'll get back to you once someone gets assigned to look at the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Poner la etiqueta en la lista negra!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

We blocked this tag for y'all back in February of 2021, so it should not be possible to use this tag any longer. Please let me know if you have any concerns or if anything seems to not be working correctly.

Comment: Es español, alguien que le traduzca XD???

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent dice que la etiqueta la bloquearon alv y que al que le preocupe que le diga

Comment: y en donde se le encuentra ?? ya yo puse por que no deberia de borrarce completamente ... https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5313/46896

Answer (score -1):

No poner la etiqueta en la lista negra.. si no aparece nunca

Answer (score -1):

**No me parece correcto:**

La etiqueta [problema] puede ser usada para asociarla a preguntas de Tipo Matemáticos o la representación de una ecuación en programación; yo sugeriría una desambiguación ( `ecuación`, `algoritmia`, `sumatoria`, `teorema` ) pero no una eliminación total de la etiqueta.

Comment: yo sigo prefiriendo que usen etiquetas específicas como ecuación, algoritmia, sumatoria, etc

Comment: ha eso me refiero con desambiguar ... la etiqueta

Comment: y yo me refiero a que las pongan desde el principio

Comment: En mi opinion, la etiqueta "problema" es poco descriptiva. Que es? un problema de programación? o un problema matematico? Sin embargo, estoy de acuerdo con la desambiguación. A pesar de eso, nuestro sitio es de programación, no de matematicas. Puede que un problema de programación sea en realidad puramente matematico (y ya hay un sitio en SE para problemas matematicos).

Comment: @DanteS. No es cierto hay script hechos en R que requieren de una interpretacion matematica o estan relacionadas a la representacion de una relacion Matematica; y hacerlo con if else tomaría mucho código ... en este caso el lenguaje implementa métodos nativos relacionados a la programación y a la resolución de problemas matemáticos y no tiene nada que ver con el sitio de Matemáticas en donde no te van a dejar expresarte en código o lenguaje de programación ... pero  parece que la comunidad aun no esta preparada para hablar de estos temas ...

Comment: Por eso dije "puede que", no "que" en realidad se trate de un problema matematico. Me refiero al tipo de preguntas que dicen que calculo debo hacer para lograr x cosa y creen que es un problema de programación por que quieren implementar ese calculo en Python.

Comment: creo que ese no es el tipo de preguntas asociado a ... a las que me refieron son a las que dicen algo como: **dada la ecuación tal (código en R), estoy aplicando el siguiente script para obtener la matriz de datos o números reales, pero el resultado no es el esperado, que error estoy cometiendo?** y le mete la etiqueta de `algoritmia` o la de `ecuación` ... es aceptable su pregunta se basa en un problema de programación ...

Comment: este seria un ejemplo (aunque le falte el código de lo que ha intentando hacer): https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495562/interpolacion-de-polinomios-de-lagrange-en-rstudio

Comment: debería de tener la etiqueta de ecuación, algoritmia o teorema