# ¿Deberíamos eliminar la etiqueta [instalacion]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado, solicitud-de-lista-negra

Actualmente hay 77 preguntas con la etiqueta [instalacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instalacion)

Algunas de ellas están relacionadas a errores o la instalación de sistemas operativos, programas, bases de datos o librerias/dependencias.

¿Deberíamos mantener esta etiqueta?

Comment: Si te fijas, hay etiquetas con menos preguntas. Personalmente, empezaría por esas. Por ejemplo [tag:traduccion], [tag:visual-basic-script] o incluso [tag:odenacion] que está mal escrito.

Comment: Por que no argumentas por que quieres eliminarla ... en meta lo que se busca es que se apoye algo que propones ... tu pregunta evade el objetivo de META ... como dice Mateo por que no borran otras etiquetas con menos preguntas o con objetivos absurdos.

Comment: Si no lo has hecho aún por favor lee [Criterios para la solicitud-de-quemado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/65)